# Using the same directive more than once in the same form

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble with a task that seems trivial to me, but I just haven't got it right yet. I have a form and in that form I use a home-cooked directive called time-range. This directive has two input fields for start-date and end-date. Later on, in the view where the form is defined I want to validate each field using code similar to this:

```
<li ng-show="form.createAssignment.fromDateField.$error.dateinput">{{::$parent.lang.from_date | capitalize}} {{::$parent.lang.has_to_be_on_format}} {{::$parent.lang.yyyy_mm_dd}}</li>
```

Well, this works just fine, BUT only for validating the input field in the last directive in the form. If I enter something wrong in the first directive, the form is invalid (and thus the error list is shown) but the text that specifies what is wrong does not show up, presumably because the input in the last directive is correct.

So, somehow I would like to be able to qualify which directive I refer to, maybe something like:

```
<li ng-show="form.createAssignment.directive1.fromDateField.$error.dateinput">{{::$parent.lang.from_date | capitalize}} {{::$parent.lang.has_to_be_on_format}} {{::$parent.lang.yyyy_mm_dd}}</li>
```

However, I haven't yet succeeded with this. Does anyone have a suggestion how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-form uses input name for validation, so it's hard to target specific input if you are using ng-repeat or repeated directives.

One option would be using ng-form directive, which means creating an inner form inside the form. There are plenty of guides on how to do this.

Another option would be passing a unique name (prefix/suffix) via your directive parameter. But unfortunately the variable name won't work automatically, you'll have to compile the template again after the name is passed in.

Comment: You are correct. I have an ng-repeat directive that causes the problem. Introducing an ng-form seems to solve it but I may have to restructure my layout to present errors in a intuitive way.

Comment: If you are displaying error under each input, then it is just param name changing. If it is centralized (e.g all on top or bottom), then not so easy ><